# timed automata - advance only in certain states

Tags: automata, real-time

I am currently looking into timed automata for a project.
I am thinking about a timed automaton where a clock only advances when the automaton is in a certain state.
However, my little knowledge in the domain makes me wonder whether somebody already defined timed automata like that.

As an example:
I.e. I have a timed automaton with two states: *L<sub>0</sub>* and *L<sub>1</sub>*.
My clock is *c* - the total time that the automaton spent in time L<sub>1</sub>.

The clock *c* should only advance when the automaton is in state *L1*.

(see upper part of drawing)

**Solution with my existing knowledge (not very elegant):**

I can see a way where I could use event-clock automata (1) to achieve this, by triggering an event *a* and on entering *L<sub>1</sub>* the value of *c* is set to:
*c* := *c* - x<sub>a</sub>
where *x<sub>a</sub>* is the time since event *a*.
(See lower part of the drawing)

However, I'm not convinced of this solution as it is inelegant, further I'm not sure whether timed automata allow for the *setting* of clocks. So far I only read about *reset* to zero.

(1) http://pub.ist.ac.at/~tah/Publications/a_determinizable_class_of_timed_automata.pdf

[image: Diagram schema of the automaton I'm looking for]

Comment: Possibly useful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counter_automaton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after looking deeper into the subject I found the solution. Posting in case somebody else needs an answer and is unfamiliar with the subject.

What I was looking for is called a Stopwatch Automaton (SWA) and allows the time to stop or advance (by specifying the derivative of a clock `c' = {0, 1}`).
Reference: The Impressive Power of Stopwatches. Franck Cassez, Kim Larsen
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.123.669&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Further I discovered that Hourglass automata also allow time to stop, but additionally also to reverse: `c' = {-1, 0, 1}`.
They however require the specification of a maximum clock value after which "all the sand passed through the hourglass" and the clock does not advance further.
Reference: Hourglass Automata.
Yuki Osada, Tim French, Mark Reynolds, Harry Smallbone
https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.5965